# Connect to UDP Port 5566 via Browser

Tags: browser, udp, ip-camera

I bought an IP-Camera which normally uses an mobile app to establish the first connection. The camera provides a WLAN I can log into using the standard password written on the camera. Now I want to connect to the Camera/Router. I found out the IP address which is `10.10.10.1` and the only open port is `5566` and it is UDPplus. I cannot open up a connection in the browser using `10.10.10.1:5566`. Is the camera connection somehow broken so I should return it or is there a different way to establish a connection to an UDPplus port?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to access a UDP port by default